# Putting a JSlider into a java code...?

Tags: java, swing

I'm drawing a circle and displaying the radius and diameter on the bottom of the GUI. I got the circle and everything in the GUI to work but was having issues putting in a JSlider where you can adjust the radius and diameter within the GUI. How would I go about doing this? Would it go in the super class?

Here's the code. (keep in mind there are two classes)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Circle1 extends JFrame {
    private CircleCanvas theCanvas;
    private JTextArea display;

    public Circle1() {
        super("Circle1");
        theCanvas = new CircleCanvas();
        display = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        display.setText("The Radius is: " + theCanvas.getRadius() + "\nThe Diameter is: " + theCanvas.getDiameter()
                + "\nThe Area is: " + theCanvas.getArea() + "\nThe Circumference is: " + theCanvas.getCircumference());

        getContentPane().add(theCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(display, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(200, 200);
        show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Circle1 app = new Circle1();
        app.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}

class CircleCanvas extends JPanel {
    private int radius;

    public CircleCanvas() {
        radius = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 100);
        setSize(100, 100);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(0, 0, radius, radius);
    }

    public int getDiameter() {
        return (2 * radius);
    }

    public int getCircumference() {
        return (int) (2 * Math.PI * radius);
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return (int) (radius * radius * Math.PI);
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not using a `SeekBar` instead?

Comment: @Joaquin, What is a "SeekBar"? "From my quick search of the web that is an android component. This is a Swing app.

Comment: Yeah that confused me too lol. JSlider is for Object Oriented Java.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! Thought you were talking about adv Android app!

Answer (score 4):

Why not start with a working example which will show you how to better structure your code?

Start with the demo from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html).

Create a panel to hold all your components. Then you can add the slider to the panel and the canvas to the panel. The tutorial uses a BoxLayout, but it may be easier to use a BorderLayout. Have the canvas display in the CENTER and the slider in the NORTH or SOUTH.

Comment: Yes, I want the slider below the circle. I will look at the link provided. Thank you

Comment: Would the method for the slider go with the main class or the sub-class?

Comment: Read the tutorial and play with the demo code before asking questions so you can understand the design of the demo code. You should not have any application code in the main() method.